# Navigation link from case to account

Tags: visualforce, javascript, navigation

I need to add a link from a Case to the Account that is related to the case on a custom  visualforce page. When the page is rendered the account id in the url is not generated.

Link in visualforce:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='/{!Case.Account.Id}'">Employer</a>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='/'">Employer</a>
```

Comment: Just use `Case.AccountId`... Are you sure the value is not null? Also in general it is better practice to do `URLFOR($Action.Account.View, Case.AccountId)`.

Comment: Why cann't you add <a href='../{!Case.Account.Id}">Employer</a>. This should work give a try.

Comment: @Suri Why would you traverse up a directory? That relative url would not work in a lot of contexts.

Comment: I am using this most of the times and especially when the vf page is embeeded into a standard page. Yes I heared this relative url give trouble some times, but I didnt came across such situation.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, the url for action generates an error' Invalid parameter for function URLFOR'

Comment: Once again...verify that your `AccountId` is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, Case.AccountId)}">
    Employer
</apex:outputLink>
```